# How to Find() a Table Row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out some easy code to convert a row of a table into an array, using only the table name and an string I know is in the first column.

```
foundRow = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("tableName").Range.Find("searchTerm").Row + 1 'Offset 1 because of the header

myArray = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("tableName").ListRows(foundRow).Range
```

I tested both lines of code in the immediate window and they do what I want, but I get "Run-time error '9': Subscrit out of range" from the first line when I put it in the code. Can someone tell me what I've done wrong? Or maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should qualify the workbook the worksheet is in. I would use `Application.Match` here personally.

Comment: if cannot find text then range.find -> nothing so nothing.row -> error, I think so

Comment: let's try: Set c = range.Find("searchTerm", lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then foundRow =c.row+1 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DatabodyRange` property to avoid awkward offsets to account for headers, and `Match()` to find the value in the first column:

```
Sub tester()

    Dim m, lo As ListObject, myArray

    Set lo = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("tableName")

    m = Application.Match("searchTerm", lo.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)

    If Not IsError(m) Then
        myArray = lo.DataBodyRange.Rows(m).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `On Error Resume Next`

**Remarks:**

- You don't need to qualify the workbook or worksheet if you're going to look in the workbook where the macro is run.
- You can use `Range("TableName").ListObject`
- When using `On Error Resume Next`, be sure you're not omiting other errors, and reset the error handler with `On Error Goto 0` or whatever you set it to.

---

```
Public Sub GetRowDataIntoArray()

    Dim rowFound As Long
    Dim rowData As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    ' This would search in column 1 the search term and return the row if found, or raise an error if not
    rowFound = Range("tableName").ListObject.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Find("searchTerm").Row

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        rowData = Range("tableName").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows(rowFound).Value
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That's embarrassing... I put my variables in quotation marks, that was causing the error :(

Anyway, thanks to Tim Williams for teaching me about `Application.Match` (instead of `Range.Find()`) and `.DataBodyRange` to simplify the address result. I decided not to use `IsError` because if the code doesn't find anything, then I made a mistake. Here's the solution I settled on:

```
myArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(tableName).ListRows( _
Application.Match(searchTerm, Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(tableName).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)).Range))
```

I used `Application.Transpose` twice to make the final array one-dimensional and easier to use